# custom validator is not working in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Width="127px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="TextBox3" 
                ErrorMessage="Must Be 8 characters" 
                onservervalidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate"     
                ValidateEmptyText="True" 
                ValidationGroup="g1">*</asp:CustomValidator>
  <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" Text="LogIn" 
                ValidationGroup="g1" Width="83px" />


 protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, 
                      ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Value.Length == 8)
        {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
        else
            args.IsValid = false;
    }
```

I want textbox to take 8 characters.But the event is not getting fired up.I haved tried by taking Required Field Validator as well as ValidateEmptyText to true but either of them is not working
Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `RequiredFieldValidator` for the TextBox too, and it should trigger the custom validator server validate event.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"   
    ControlToValidate="TextBox3" 
    ErrorMessage="Required">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: I have tried it using Required Field Validator also,it is not working